# How to setup 2 dsl lines on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, dsl

I have an issue with a Windows 2008 R2 Standard server. Currently we have 12 workstations cabled to a switch. The switch is fed by 1 AT&T 6mb DSL Modem. One NIC on the server connects to the switch. All 12 workstations connect to the internet and share a folder on the local lan. To increase internet speed I have had AT&T install another separate 6mb DSL line.

How do I setup the NIC's on the server and the 2 DSL lines properly so the workstations can access the internet and see the shared folder?

Paul, That's what I want to do. Currently all 12 users are connected to one switch, which is fed by 1 dsl line. I have had another dsl line installed. I want to add another switch and put 6 of the users on the new switch with the new dsl line. I don't know how to configure the second network card properly, which will cable into the second switch. –

Comment: Welcome to Super User. No need to "sign" your questions as it is done automatically. You can help us help you by [edit]ing your question to include what have you researched or attempted so far.

Comment: It is unlikely you can achieve what you want with what you have.  There are a couple of options - purchase a router that supports load balancing internet connections, or splitting your network in half, and having 6 users for each connection (assuming the users are the source of the slowness).  Please [edit] your question and give more info about the situation.

Comment: Paul, That's what I want to do.  Currently all 12 users are connected to one switch, which is fed by 1 dsl line.  I have had another dsl line installed.  I want to add another switch and put 6 of the users on the new switch with the new dsl line.  I don't know how to configure the second network card properly, which will cable into the second switch.